# Penalize documents with a lot of unique terms in lucene

Tags: lucene, similarity

My purpose is to find animals(doc) given a city (term)

I've indexed documents this way:

```
doc1(bear)  = [city1, city2, city2, city3..]
doc2(dog)   = [city1, city1, city1, city2, city2, city2, city3, city3, city3..]
..
```

I'd like to penalize (animals)documents that appear in a lot of cities, therefore documents with an high percentage of different cities/all cities like "dog".

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It already does!

See [Similarity.computeNorm](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html#computeNorm%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInvertState%29).

The norm function, by default, considers matches on shorter fields to be a more precise match, and so scores them higher than longer fields.

If you need this to have a heavier impact, you can override the DefaultSimilarity with a custom version, and modify the value returned from the computeNorm method to weigh the lengthNorm portion of the calculation more heavily.  I'd recommend just adding a multiplier somewhere in the existing algorithm, if you need to do that, but tweak it however you need to.

Note!  As stated in the API, this value is stored in the index, not computed at query time.  You must reindex to see changes take effect.

---

The calculation in computeNorm (3.6.0) is:

```
state.getBoost() * ((float) (1.0 / Math.sqrt(numTerms)))
```

Where numterms is the total number of terms in the field, and state is a [FieldInvertState](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/FieldInvertState.html).

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, problem is I only want to penalize "peak" documents, i.e. animals very common with present in a lot of cities AND I DON'T want to boost animals very rare. This because very rare animals usually have a really low term freq and get boosted up only because they often have a low field norm. I need to retrieve animals with high term freq (cutting off only the really common ones).

Comment: Okay, that's a bit more complicated, sure, and requires you to define what the "peak" is.  But the answer is still the same.  Implement your logic in a custom Similarity, extending DefaultSimilarity, with an implementation of computeNorm that meets your requirements, then reindex using it.

Comment: Ok, thanks.. could you post any rough sample code on how to do it? I was thinking to use conditional probability http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability and boost, and indexing with no field norms. I.E. dividing the number of unique cities(terms) connected to dog by tot num of unique cities. Than boosting the document using the inverse of that probability factor. Eg. doc * boost 1/Pfactor[P(dog cities)/P(cities)]. I can calculate conditional probability off lucene. Does this approach make sense?

Comment: I don't know what I could provide, other than a skeleton of a DefaultSimilatiry subclass.  I'd copy over the source from DefaultSimilarity.computeNorm(), to get a starting point at least on how to pull the relevant data from the FieldInvertState.  As far as whether your conditional probability algorithm makes sense, I can't really answer that.  Seems plausible enough, but I don't know your requirements.